# How to stop showing loading icon in browser

Tags: html, ajax, google-chrome, safari, comet

I have a Comet application which send long polling requests (by AJAX) immediately after page load. Request are long waiting, so browser (e.g. Safari or Chrome) will leave his loading icon in loading mode, which makes users feel that the page is still loading.

Is there any way to stop showing loading icon in browser when page already loaded and before AJAX long polling requests in progress ?

Comment: Is there any change in the behaviour if you have a delay before starting the ajax requests

Comment: If the task is *really* long, like tens of seconds / minutes, it might be more viable to send request to start the processing that returns immediately and then check the server status periodically, grabbing the result if done.

Comment: @MikulasDite this is a comet application (e.g. "chat") which actually can be run hours, days or even weeks. Periodically checking is very bad in terms of performance and server load, so Comet technology is preferred.

Comment: @Paystey what delay you mean ? How much time ? I think it is not a problem to wait about 1 sec, but since it is a chat application, I don't want to wait to much.

Comment: @Epsiloncool Right, I've missed that part. In that case, consider using html5 sockets, that might be a little more gentle to your server.

Comment: @MikulasDite Thank you, I have analysed options of websockets, but this technology is not sufficiently reliable, not all browsers support it, the format of the protocol is changed every month, in addition, the standard is not yet officially accepted. Besides, I not understand how a periodic check (ping) implemented on websockets. Therefore I've chosen of Comet as the most reliable.

Comment: @Paystey Thank you. Adding the 100ms delay before first Comet request stopping browser's loading icon.

Comment: @Epsiloncool Yeh that's what I was thinking, just a short one to let the browser get itself together. Glad it worked, I'll have to remember this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have been successful removing the "loading" indicator in Safari 5.1.5 with ajax long polling requests. Chrome unfortunately still consistently shows the loading indicator. For chrome, our team has chosen to simply change the css cursor value on the entire body element (ex: crosshair or a custom cursor) - a terrible "hack" - but at least the user won't see the loading mouse cursor while they are on the system.

Comment: well, and how did you remove the "loading" indicator in safari (as that was the question)?